# Why are certain characters appearing 'broken' in JS console.log?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vim, unicode, ascii

I'm downloading a file in javascript and it contains some special characters, for example if I open it in vim or less I see a line that contains `caf<E9>`, where `<E9>` is a special character hex value.

If you look up the hex value for E9 it is `é`, so the whole line is `café`, but if I do a `console.log` on that line, I don't get `café` but I get `caf�`. Why would that be?

How can I replace that strange value `�` with `é`? None of these seem to work.

```
line.replace(/\x92/g, '')
line.replace('\x92', '')
```

The file contains different hex characters (special single and double quotation marks) that appear the same way. Why would they be appearing like this in the first place, and how can I fix them?

Some additional info that might help: When I open the file in vim it says `[converted]` at the bottom. Apparently that means it converted it from the value of the `fileencoding` vim property (which is `latin1`) to the value of the `encoding` vim property (which is `utf-8`).

Comment: The byte 0xE9 alone is not a valid character in UTF-8, and this why vim is not showing it as "é". To represent "é" in UTF-8 it takes two bytes: 0xC3 xA9. To see 0xE9 as "é" you need to download the file with a different encoding, like latin1.

Answer (score 3):

```
console.log(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(0xe9,10)))
```

Use parseInt to convert to decimal and then get the character code. To convert the character back:

```
parseInt((é).charCodeAt(0), 16) <==== doesn't work check out the link below
```

MDN has a method for extending the charCodeAt to cover the multilingual characters.  Check out this link with code and example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt

Comment: How could I convert those strange characters back to their 'normal' versions though? Any idea what is causing this to begin with?

Comment: I added a link to MDN that explains the issue with converting back, there is a code solution there that could help.

Comment: This only works if the file in question is served as ISO-8559-1. If the file contains curly quotes, the encoding is probably windows-1252, and this method will fail.

Comment: @roeland When I use the `file` command to figure out the encoding of the file, it says `Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines`. When downloading the file, what encoding should I use for this file? I know the file also contains curly quotes (e.g. appearing as `<92>` in vim), so you say `latin1` encoding would fail? If I want to try windows-1252, what code would I set as the encoding? From https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite the closest I can see is `win1251`, is it the right one?

Comment: There's no way to know for sure. Normally the web server gives you the encoding in the `content-type` header. Note that a curly quote `“` is *U+201C*, while *U+0092* is a control character.